# Can't push or pull from VS Code on remote SSH

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote-ssh

I managed to connect to the remote via SSH, but I can't push or pull from VS Code.

This is the error that pops up:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

This is my configuration file:

```
Host my_host
  HostName my_host
  User my_name
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.ppk
```

In order for the remote connection to work, I have to use the private key with .ppk extension, maybe this is what is causing this issue.

This is how my .ssh folder looks like:

[image]

I tried the workaround in here, but it didn't work for me:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13680#issuecomment-414841885